# Screen error after flashing custom recovery

Tags: android, adb, samsung-galaxy

I have a new Samsung Galaxy TAB A 6 (SM-T580) that I want to root, so I downloaded Odin and TWRP 3.1.1. I'm able to enter download mode and flash TWPR, but after that when  I try to reboot to recovery or system it shows blue and red horizontal lines, I can  interact with the screen (I can push buttons if I know where they are looking other tablets working properly.) How can I solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. If anyone is facing this problem, it's because in the last firmware Samsung did patch something, TWRP has launched a version to solve this issue ((twrp_3.2.3-1_sm-t580_29918.tar). I found this answer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidroot/comments/9l4itl/twrp_recovery_mode_blue_lines_red_lines/)

Comment: Thanks, life saver!